# Moving rows to another sheet with Apps Script, but doesn't work with shared document

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script helping me both generate a started date by a conditional column, and also moving a row to another sheet by a "Done" Column. When I use the document it works without any issues, but when others use the document the rows aren't moved to the separate sheet. Anyone got any ideas what it could be?

`

```
function onEdit(e) {
first(e);
second(e);

function first(e) {
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();

if(
  e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() == 'B2B_LeadList' 
  &&
 col === 22 
  && 
  e.value == 'STARTED' 
  &&
e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,23).setValue(new Date()== '' 
&& 
 row > 1)){
 
e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,23).setValue(new Date());
}}

function second(e){
var mainSheet = 'B2B_LeadList'
var targetSheet = 'B2B_Archive'

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var range = sheet.getActiveRange();

if(sheet.getName() == 'B2B_LeadList' && e.range.getColumn() == 35 && e.range.getValue() == 'YES'){
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var numColumns = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('B2B_Archive');
  var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1,1);
  e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,36).setValue(new Date());
  sheet.getRange(row,1,1,numColumns).moveTo(target);
  sheet.deleteRow(row);
} 
}

}
```

`

I am expecting that other users working in this document can move rows from current sheet to another sheet by selecting "YES" in a "Done?" column.

Comment: They all have edit permission, right?

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == 'B2B_LeadList' && e.range.columnStart === 22 && e.range.rowStart > 1 && e.value == 'STARTED') {
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 23).setValue(new Date());
  }
  if (sh.getName() == 'B2B_LeadList' && e.range.columnStart == 35 && e.value == 'YES') {
    var tsh = e.source.getSheetByName('B2B_Archive');
    var trg = tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 36).setValue(new Date());
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).moveTo(trg);
    sh.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
  }
}
```

If you are moving the script to their account make sure they authorize it.  Otherwise ensure that they have permission to edit the file.  Also note that this is a simple trigger and cannot perform functions which require permission.

Comment: ! Thanks for that. I asked my collegues to run the script themselves from their accounts, and they went through and allowed the permissions process. Are you saying that wont help either? Would I have to create the trigger as an installable trigger?